# NameError: name 'find_element' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a code with selenium but it shows the following error 'NameError: name 'find_element' is notdefined', can you help me?. Thankss

button_login = find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')

button_login.click()

sleep(2)

Answer (score 0):

To use the `find_element` you first need to instantiate a webdriver object:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your_url")
button_login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
button_login.click()

time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: already used these commands

Comment: @laurino Then you need to update your posted code with a [mcve]... the actual code you are using because you posted code doesn't have these.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` method should be applied on `driver` object of `webdriver` type.
So, instead of

```py
button_login = find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
```

It should be something like

```py
button_login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
```

Where `driver` is previously defined and initialized in the way as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
```

Comment: thanks, I got part, but now the following check with the following error: ''selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":" /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1 ]/div[1]/a/div[1]/div[2]"}

Comment: i'm learning to program, the bot is able to log in and pass the first part, but soon after this error appears